# Infinite Loop When Using Function Return Value as a Statement

Tags: c++, function, loops, do-while

Was making a small code for a text based game but i tried to do thinks a bit different than the tutorial sort of to test my understanding but i tried to get a function value to make a do while statement but it seems whether the statement false or true the code just keep looping infinitely im a beginner so pls if you have a time explain why the code is faulty and Thank you in Advance

The main function

```
int main() {

    PrintIntroStart();
    do {
        PlayGame();
        AskToPlayAgain();
    } while (AskToPlayAgain() == true);
    return 0;
}
```

the Bool Function

```
bool AskToPlayAgain(){
//Asking The Player Whether To Play Again Or Not
std::string PlayerResponse = "";

std::cout << "Do You Want To Play Again? (Yes/No)" << std::endl;
std::cin >> PlayerResponse;
if (PlayerResponse[0] == 'y' || 'Y') 
    return true;
else
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Last four lines of your function should be `return (PlayerResponse[0] == 'y' || PlayerResponse[0] == 'Y')`.

Comment: Remove the `AskToPlayAgain();` from inside the loop, you only need it in the `while (AskToPlayAgain());` part.

Answer (score 3):

Also, here you are asking twice to play again

```
do {
    PlayGame();
    AskToPlayAgain();
   } while (AskToPlayAgain() == true);
```

this should be

```
do {
    PlayGame();
} while (AskToPlayAgain() == true);
```

Comment: oh i see so even if the function is inside the statement c++ will still run it first instead of directly getting the value is that it?

Comment: Yes, every time you invoke function it executes.

Answer (score 2):

`if (PlayerResponse[0] == 'y' || 'Y')` this one should be

```
if (PlayerResponse[0] == 'y' || PlayerResponse[0] == 'Y')
```

Otherwise your `if` condition is always true, because `'Y'` itself is non-zero.

And in fact you don't need this `if` statement, just

```
return PlayerResponse[0] == 'y' || PlayerResponse[0] == 'Y';
```

Comment: " because 'Y' itself in non-zero. "  can i ask what do you mean by this? cause i thought codes will check the matching Ascii value with the intended one.But i might be wrong

Comment: Sorry Nvm i didnt read the bottom answer

Comment: Just remember C is not like a natural language. `PlayerResponse[0] == 'y' || 'Y'` this one might be natural for human, but not compiler. For compiler, it means `(PlayerResponse[0] == 'y') || 'Y'. Thus `'Y'` is not comparing to the `PlayerResponse[0]`.

Comment: why you did not mentioned the problem in the main function? and you are doing copy-paste from comments..

Comment: @EzizDurdyyev Please check the time for post, my answer is 12:24:34, your comment is 12:30:09. Who was copying ?

Comment: @EzizDurdyyev If this is your reason for downvote, please remove it, it's ridiculous.

Comment: yes, maybe you answered it at 12:24:34, but you edited it right after my comment. I mean it is not a big deal for me. But SO must find a solution for problems like this. This is not even an answer. You and @ziza could just mention it in comments section. Anyways..

Comment: @EzizDurdyyev No. Answer is answer, comment is comment, they are different things. "Comments exist so that users can talk about questions and answers without posting new answers **that do not make an attempt to answer the question asked**." Quoted from [how do comments works](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work)

Answer (score 0):

So first of all, you are only checking the outcome of the game every second play.
You should follow @ziza s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48826946/3181761) and remove the function call inside the loop.

The second problem, that causes the infinite loop is your input check.
A bool value in c++ is not a single bit, but just anoter regular value that is evaluated as `false` if it is 0 and to `true` if it has any other value. In your case the first comparison will evauate to 1 if the player input is 'y' and the second part of the condition will be the value of the 'Y' character (which is not 0). So your condition will always be `true` like @liliscent [stated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48826723/3181761).